# Import Google Contacts - How to exclude State/Country (DE,USA etc)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

How to exclude a contact detail from being imported (to sheets)?
I want to import contacts including the address field, but without the State (USA,DE etc).

im using .getAddresses()

The Result is: 
Max Mustermann 
First street 1 
88662 Uberlingen 
**DE**

I want the Address without the "**DE**":

Max Mustermann

First street 1

88662 Uberlingen

Greetings from Germany and thanks for the help in Advance!
Nico

**Its not my Code - i only edited it for my needs:**

```js
function getContacts(groupName) {
  Utilities.sleep(200);
  
  if(groupName !== "") {
    var group  = ContactsApp.getContactGroup(groupName);
  } else {
    groupName = 'System Group: My Contacts';
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(group);
  
  var allContacts = []; 
  var contactDetails = [];
  var data, numData, dataArray = [], extraArray = [];
  var contact_length = contacts.length;
  //var index = 0;
  var i = 0,batch_limit = 500;
  if(contact_length == 0)
  {
    if(groupName == '')
    {
       Browser.msgBox("Keine Kontakte in deinem Account gefunden");  
    }
    else
    {
       Browser.msgBox("Keine Kontakte in "+groupName);
    }    
    return;
  }
  else if(contact_length > 7000)
  {
    Browser.msgBox("Too many contacts.Can process upto 7000 contacts only");
    return;
  }
  for(i; i < contact_length; i++) {
    allContacts[i] = [];
    //contactDetails[0] = index++;

    contactDetails[1] = contacts[i].getPrefix();
    contactDetails[2] = contacts[i].getGivenName();
    contactDetails[3] = contacts[i].getFamilyName();
    contactDetails[0] = contacts[i].getNickname();
    
    
    //contactDetails[3] = contacts[i].getSuffix();
    
    //data = contacts[i].getEmails(); ----- original
    // data = contacts[i].getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL); // ----- modified
    data = contacts[i].getEmails(); // ----- modified
    numData = data.length;
    for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
      dataArray[j] = data[j].getAddress();
    }
    //contactDetails[3] = dataArray.toString(); ----- original
    contactDetails[6] = dataArray.join("\n");  // ----- modified
    dataArray = [];
    
    data = contacts[i].getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE); // ----- modified
    numData = data.length;
    for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
      dataArray[j] = data[j].getPhoneNumber();
    }
    //contactDetails[4] = dataArray.toString(); ------ original
    contactDetails[7] = dataArray.join("\n");  // ----- modified
    dataArray = [];

    //data = contacts[i].getContactGroups(); // <-- This call takes anywhere between 0.03 seconds to 1.45 seconds. 
    data = contacts[i].getContactGroups();
    numData = data.length;
    for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
      if(data[j].getName() == 'System Group: My Contacts')
      {
        continue;
      }
      else
      {
        dataArray[j] = data[j].getName();
        Logger.log(dataArray[i]);
      }
    }
    //contactDetails[9] = dataArray.toString(); ------ original
    contactDetails[11] = dataArray.join("\n");  // ----- modified
    dataArray = [];
    
    //data = contacts[i].getPhones(); ----- original
    data = contacts[i].getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE); // ----- modified
    numData = data.length;
    for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
      dataArray[j] = data[j].getPhoneNumber();
    }
    //contactDetails[4] = dataArray.toString(); ------ original
    contactDetails[8] = dataArray.join("\n");  // ----- modified
    dataArray = [];
    
    // new section for home_phone ----- start
    data = contacts[i].getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_PHONE);
    numData = data.length;
    for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++){
      dataArray[j] = data[j].getPhoneNumber();
    }
    contactDetails[9] = dataArray.join("\n");
    dataArray = [];
    // new section for home_phone ----- end
    
    data = contacts[i].getCompanies();
    numData = data.length;
    for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
      dataArray[j] = data[j].getCompanyName();
      extraArray[j] = data[j].getJobTitle();
    }
    //contactDetails[5] = dataArray.toString(); ----- original
    contactDetails[4] = dataArray.join("\n");  // ----- modified
    dataArray = [];
    //contactDetails[6] = extraArray.toString(); ------ original
    contactDetails[5] = extraArray.join("\n");  // ----- modified
    
    data = contacts[i].getAddresses();
    numData = data.length;
    for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
      dataArray[j] = data[j].getAddress();
    }
    //contactDetails[7] = dataArray.join("\n"); ------ original
    contactDetails[10] = dataArray.join("\n");  // ----- modified
    dataArray = [];
    
    contactDetails[12] = contacts[i].getNotes();
    
    data = contacts[i].getCustomFields();
    numData = data.length;
    for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
      dataArray[j] = data[j].getValue();
    }
    //contactDetails[7] = dataArray.join("\n"); ------ original
    contactDetails[20] = dataArray.join("\n");  // ----- modified
    dataArray = [];  
    data = [];
    
    contactDetails[14] = 'saved';
    contactDetails[15] = contacts[i].getId();

    for(var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
      allContacts[i][j] =  contactDetails[j];
    }    
    Logger.log(i);
    printContacts(allContacts, i);
  }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Madhavi posted it

Answer (score 1):

With the ContactsApp service you'll have to use string manipulation on your end. Because addresses returned by the method [`getAddress()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/address-field#getaddress) are returned as a string, so you have to process this string with your code, to remove the part you don't want.

Another option would be to use the [People API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people) where the address is returned as json, which is much better for what you want.

You can get the addresses of all your connections with the segmented address fields as json, from which you can pick the fields you want to build your object.

#### Example:

Make a `GET` request to:

> [`https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}/connections`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22addresses%22%7D)

It will return a json object like the following:

```py
{
  "connections": [
    {
      "resourceName": "people/some-resourse-name",
      "etag": "%fakedummymmydumsrVU09",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "CONTACT",
              "id": "30202bb55edssome-id"
            }
          },
          "formattedValue": "Travessera de Dalt\n08002\n08001 Barcelona\nBarcelona\nES",
          "type": "home",
          "formattedType": "Home",
          "poBox": "08002",
          "streetAddress": "Travessera de Dalt",
          "city": "Barcelona",
          "region": "Barcelona",
          "postalCode": "08001",
          "country": "ES",
          "countryCode": "ES"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "totalPeople": 1,
  "totalItems": 1
}
```

As you can see you will be able to extract those parts of the addresses that you want and ignore the rest.

Comment: is there a docomentation, how to do this? Or maybe you can give me an example with the code I posted above?

Comment: I updated my answer, there is a way using the People API